# Navigation does not work after using event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just trying to highlight the active link in my navigation:

```
$("#navigation li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#navigation li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

with this script I have used before but the issue I'm having is that it highlights the active link after click but the link is unresponsive, nothing happens after click, it won't navigate to the page.

This is my **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/wntuevrk/6/)** so you can see the code but since we can navigate to other pages it is worthless I guess. This never happened to me before. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's what `event.preventDefault()` does. It prevents the default action from carrying out (opening the link).

Comment: you could trigger a simple page navigation with javascript (like imitating the default behavior of a link wich you just prevented). But any changes would be lost after navigation anyway - so the question is: why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preventDefault() is used to prevent from the default behavior . On the other hand if page navigated , your active link will no more active since it was the previous page where all script did manipulation .

You may proceed something as below -

**Store the required list id in localstorage**

```
$("#navigation li").click(function(e) {
     store('active_link', $(this).attr('id'));
 });
```

**Required functions**

```
function setup() {
        var tmp = get('active_link');
        if (tmp)
        {
        $("#navigation li.active").removeClass("active");
        $('#'+tmp).addClass("active");
        }
    } 
    function get(name) {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
          return localStorage.getItem(name);
        } 
    }
    function store(name, val) {
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
          localStorage.setItem(name, val);
        } 
    }
```

**Now in each page , get the active list id**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 setup();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're preventing the default action with:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Remove this and the link will click through.

However then I question why you would want to update the UI with javascript as you will be immediately redirected to another page.

Answer (score 0):

After removing `e.preventDefault()` I had a new issue. When I clicked a link it got highlighted but right away the `.active` class went back to the home link. When you have an `<a href="#">` is different than having `<a href="mypage.php">`. This solution works fine for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
    $("#navigation li a").each(function() {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            $("li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
})
```

Thanks everyone!